# Correct syntax for multiple where criteria?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am trying to create a line of VBA code in MsAccess using Docmd.Openform using multiple 'where' criteria, but I am getting a "Type Mismatch error code 13" message when using the following line of code.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "ISY_Employment", acNormal, "", _
  "[Emp_PartID]='" & Me.ISYPartID & "'" And "[Emp_ID]=" & [EMPID] & "", , acNormal
```

The following lines of code each work separately and open the form based on each individual 'where' field.

```
  DoCmd.OpenForm "ISY_Employment", acNormal, "", "[Emp_ID]=" & [EMPID] & "", , acNormal


  DoCmd.OpenForm "ISY_Employment", acNormal, "", "[Emp_PartID]='" & Me.ISYPartID & "'", , acNormal
```

but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct in order for the form to open based on **both ** field criteria.

Any help or guidance on syntax would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What happened here is: the `And` is not part of the string. So it is used as operator - boolean or bitwise AND, but this is not defined for strings => type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed quoting and I think that last `acNormal` should be `acWindowNormal` (although both evaluate to zero)

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "ISY_Employment", acNormal, "", _
  "[Emp_PartID]='" & Me.ISYPartID & "' And [Emp_ID]=" & [EMPID], , acWindowNormal
```

...assuming the first value is non-numeric and the second one is numeric.